# How to generate changlogFile in.sql format?

Tags: liquibase

I did run this query to genereate changelogFile in .sql format

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
          --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar 
          --changeLogFile=test_diff.sql 
          --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/provision"
          --username=root 
          --password=** 
           diffChangeLog 
          --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/provision_old 
          --referenceUsername=root 
          --referencePassword=***
```

I get following error

```
Liquibase Update Failed: No serializer associated with the filename or extension 'sql'
SEVERE 5/2/13 12:50 PM:liquibase: No serializer associated with the filename or extension 'sql'
java.lang.RuntimeException: No serializer associated with the filename or extension 'sql'
```

Is it possible to generate changelogfile in .sql formate?

Answer (score 3):

Add param:

```
--changeLogFile=fileName.databaseType.sql
```

This is my worked sample (liquibase 3.6.3):

```
liquibase.bat^
    --changeLogFile=databaseChangeLog.oracle.sql^
    --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ^
    --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl ^
    --username=uat ^
    --password=uat ^
    diffChangeLog ^
    --referenceDriver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ^
    --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl ^
    --referenceUsername=test ^
    --referencePassword=test ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this param:

```
--changeLogFile="./changelog.mysql.sql"
```

Can refer [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html).

Comment: Serializing changelog as sql requires a file name in the format `*.databaseType.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Specifing the changelogfile name with .sql should help

```
 --changeLogFile="C:\db-changelog.oracle.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Liquibase** **v4.9.0** and this is how I generate change log file in sql format.

```
liquibase --changelog-file=mychangelog.mysql.sql generate-changelog
```

The `--changelog-file` paramater takes a file name. The file name should be in the format `FILE_NAME.DATA_BASE_TYPE.sql`.

In my case I was running on Mysql so I changed the `DATA_BASE_TYPE` to mysql.